# The value of local variable isn't used

Tags: flutter, dart, deprecated

I am new to flutter and I was following a tutorial when this error popped up. The ancestorRenderObjectOfType has deprecated and been replaced by findAncestorRenderObjectOfType so dart is throwing me errors.

**What the tutor did in his video of old dart:**

```
static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
final type = _typeOf<BlocProvider<T>>();
BlocProvider<T> provider = context
    .context.ancestorRenderObjectOfType(type); 
return provider.bloc;
```

}

static Type _typeOf() => T;
}

**What I did in my code**

```
static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
    final type = _typeOf<BlocProvider<T>>();
    BlocProvider<T> provider = context
        .findAncestorRenderObjectOfType();
    return provider.bloc;
  }

  static Type _typeOf<T>() => T;
}
```

If I put

```
BlocProvider<T> provider = context
        .findAncestorRenderObjectOfType(type);
```

I get an error saying
Too many positional arguements. 0 expected, but 1 found.

The ENTIRE code

```
abstract class BlocBase {
  void dispose();
}

//Genric Bloc provider
class BlocProvider<T extends BlocBase> extends StatefulWidget {
  BlocProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final T bloc;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  _BlocProviderState<T> createState() => _BlocProviderState<T>();

  static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
    final type = _typeOf<BlocProvider<T>>();
    BlocProvider<T> provider = context
        .findAncestorRenderObjectOfType(); //context.ancestorRenderObjectOfType(type);  GOTCHA
    return provider.bloc;
  }

  static Type _typeOf<T>() => T;
}

class _BlocProviderState<T> extends State<BlocProvider<BlocBase>> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try: `context.findAncestorRenderObjectOfType<BlocProvider<T>>();`

Comment: it gives me error:  BlocProvider<T> doesnt extend RenderObject

Answer (score 1):

`findAncestorRenderObjectOfType` doesnt take the `type` as argument instead it is a generic method where you can provide the type while calling the method. So your code will be as below:

```
static T of<T>(BuildContext context) {
  BlocProvider<T> provider = context
    .findAncestorRenderObjectOfType<BlocProvider<T>>();
  return provider.bloc;
}
```

Comment: it gives me error: BlocProvider<T> doesnt extend RenderObject

Comment: @greenycodeskii check now. What is BlocBase? How are you calling this `of` method; whicth parameters